# How to right align element using bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I need to put element to the right side of page.

This element:

[image: element]

To the right side of page. Like this:

[image]

I found only `pull-right` helper class, but I have been realizing, it wouldn't help me, because it based on `float`. So I started research and first result in google is [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422134/how-do-i-right-align-an-element-using-twitter-bootstrap). It says, that I should use `pull-right`. Well, I tried...

I tried this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Создать заказ</span></a>
```

I got this obvious result:

[image]

You can see that third `heading` in upper row is displaced.

So what exactly I need to do right align any element using bootstrap api?

I understand, that I can search `how to center/left/right div` and I will find some working results, but it will be **not** bootstrap solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your answer is **".pull-right"** class. You may look at it **[Bootstrap 3 Documentation Helper Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)**. I think you can use 2 methods for this.

**1) For amateurs :**

```
<div class="col-sm-8"></div> /*Empty div for left alignment*/
<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="btn btn-default">Your Text on Button</div></div> /*This is your button*/
```

**After this code you can use your headings. I mean your button and your heading have to apart from each other.**

But as I said this is really **terrible** for you. And I think it will occur some problem for **responsive design.**

**2)This is for pro Bootstrappers**

```
<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="btn btn-default pull-right>Your Button Text</div></div>
```

**Again after this code you can use your headings. I mean your button and your heading have to apart from each other.** You should have to get attention on **".pull-right"** class. You just use it on the right place.

I think this will be work for you!

**Maybe you want to look at it : [How can I get my Twitter Bootstrap buttons to right align?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446189/how-can-i-get-my-twitter-bootstrap-buttons-to-right-align)**

Comment: This helped me and will be accepted anyway, but I have just one question: is it neccessary to use to div's? Or can I use `div` and put `a` in it with classes `btn btn-default pull-right`?

Comment: If you want to not change your position of headings. You may look for **position:absolute** or **position:fixed** css properties. Your problem may not be about Bootstrap...

Comment: You can insert a tag inside of div. It can occur some problem if you use `.pull-right` class for **a** tag. I mean you can use that : `<div class="btn btn-default pull-right"><a href="your-sexy-link">Your Sexy Button Text</a></div>`

Comment: I have this now: [source (77-79 lines)](https://bitbucket.org/SharikovVladislav/juri-sus-help/src/3e8a83c4729542b5c00979d6f975a381abb1b9f8/www/index.php?at=master#cl-77). Will this cause problems?

Comment: I cannot access that link you can send me as email... emredoganm@live.com or use jsfiddle

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/aVBhL/) is jsfiddle. I didn't include bootstrap files, so it is simple output, but I want to show you code, not result of this code.

Comment: You can use it : http://jsfiddle.net/emredoganm/6DDhL/  Maybe you want to test what you think :-)